# Tokenize string with scanner with a String pattern

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, token, bufferedreader, readline

I have to tokenize a String in which the tokens are divided by " - ".

```
String temp = in.readLine();
input_scanner = new Scanner(temp);

token_temp_token_1 = input_scanner.next();
token_temp_token_2 = input_scanner.next(" - ");
token_temp_token_3 = input_scanner.next(" - ");
System.out.println(token_temp_token_1 + " " + token_temp_token_3);
```

It doesn't print anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure about which input you're typing and what you expect your code to do, but this should get you started:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String[] parts = scanner.nextLine().split(" - "); 
System.out.println(parts[0] + " " + parts[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
    String temp = in.readLine();
    input_scanner = new Scanner(temp);

    token_temp_token_1 = input_scanner.next();
    token_temp_token_2 = input_scanner.skip(" - ").next();
    token_temp_token_3 = input_scanner.skip(" - ").next();
    System.out.println(token_temp_token_1 + " " + token_temp_token_3);
```

Or something like this:

```
    String temp = in.readLine();
    input_scanner = new Scanner(temp);

    String[] tokens = input_scanner.nextLine().split(" - ");
    if (tokens.length > 2){
        System.out.println(tokens[0] + " " + tokens[2]);
    }
    input_scanner.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next-java.lang.String-), the argument of method `public String next(String pattern)` is not delimiter, but a regular expression that matches your token, which is equivalent to this:

```
Pattern tokenRegex = Pattern.compile(someRegex);
Matcher tokenizer = tokenRegex.matches(contentToBeTokenized);
List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
while(tokenizer.find()){
    String token = tokenizer.group();
    tokens.add(token)
}
```

You should rather use `someString.split(delimiter)` to delimit a String; this will return an array of strings divided by the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

It's depend on your input and your token. If you code as follow:

```
String str = "Hello World";
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(str);

System.out.println(scanner.next("Hello"));
System.out.println(scanner.next("World"));
```

you will see the result. Printing Hello and World in the next line.
the parameter of scanner.next(String pattern) should not begin with " ".